# Access relate tables

Tags: database, ms-access, relationship

I have two tables (SD and Species_Mar28_2023) in Access and I have joined them using the Relationships database tool. As shown in image below I joined them using the CODEffs field (numeric) which is a unique code to identify species. SD can have repeated CODEffs values (a table of observations in the field) whereas Species_Mar28_2023 has each value only once (using this as a lookup table to get species name). When I open the SD table I want to expand each record (using the "+") and see the corresponding values from the Species_Mar28_2023 table. However the opposite happens - I see the SD records in the species table. I tried Edit Relationship to switch the tables but it still reverts back. How can I force the species table to relate to the SD table?

[image: Relationship View in Access]

Comment: The link must go to `Species_Mar28_2023.ID`, the key.

Comment: Tables should be related on key fields - designated primary key of one table and foreign key of related table. If you want to link on CODEffs field of Species table then assign it as primary key, not ID field. Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables. Nor use reserved words as names - Name is a reserved word.

Comment: Why does Species table have a date in its name?

Comment: Actually, Access has made correct assumption in the '+' expansion. This is supposed to display the 'many' side of a relationship. What you want is backwards. Build a form for the SD table with a combobox for Species. Combobox RowSource should include all fields then textboxes can refer to those columns by index to display this related data. Example: `=cbxSpecies.Column(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the result by writing an SQL query and creating a new table.

SELECT *
FROM SD INNER JOIN Species ON SD.CODEffs = Species.CODEffs